# WCF - IIS is not getting .net 3.0

Tags: wcf, iis

Deployment of a WCF Service in the IIS is giving the following error:

```
Server Error in '/calc' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The unrecognized directive 'Service' is specified.

Source Error:

Line 7:  
Line 8:  
Line 9:  <%@ Service Class="Calculator.CalculatorService" %>
Line 10: <%@ Assembly Name="CalculatorService" %>


Source File: /calc/Service.svc    Line: 9

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

I have studied [these](http://www.stackpanel.com/tag/iis/) suggestions. But it didn't work.

What can be the problem?

Comment: show us the contents of your *.svc file!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you are missing the `ServiceHost` to begin the directive for the service..

IE:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Calculator.CalculatorService" %>
```

P.S.  .NET 3.0 & 3.5 are assembly releases on top of the 2.0 Runtime, the framework won't say version 3.0/3.5